# lodash - using intersectionWith to get intersection of arrays of objects results in a uniqueness issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am trying to intersect 2 arrays of objects by some attribute using Lodash `intersectWith`.

For example:

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
var others = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

// Intersect by objects with the same value for 'x'
_.intersectionWith(objects, others, (obj, oth) => obj.x === oth.x);
```

Doing so, I'm getting an unexpected result of just 1 object:

```
[{ x: 1, y: 1 }]
```

instead of the entire first array:

```
[{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }]
```

For some reason the `intersectionWith` function seemingly returns only unique results according to the attribute being compared.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you miss the part of [`_.intersection`](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersection):

> Creates an array of ***unique values*** that are included in all given arrays using [SameValueZero](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) for equality comparisons. The order and references of result values are determined by the first array. [***Emphasis*** by NS]

That means, if you have a checked value of `x: 1`, then no more objects with this value are included in the result set.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I have noticed this section at the documentation. it's just that i thought the expected behavior would be to apply the uniqueness on the entire entry object, and not by the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Lodash documentation on [_.intersection](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersection):

> Creates an array of unique values that are included in all given arrays using SameValueZero for equality comparisons.

Lodash documentation on [_.intersectionWith](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersectionWith)

> This method is like _.intersection except that it accepts comparator which is invoked to compare elements of arrays.

It means that your comparator determines uniqueness of values. By comparing only x you make all objects actually the same according to your custom comparator.